# How tall is the monster at the end of The Cloverfield Paradox?

Tags: cloverfield, the-cloverfield-paradox

Assuming the thing's feet were at sea level, how tall would the monster we saw roaring above the cloud deck at the end of *The Cloverfield Paradox* have to be for us to see what we saw?

Comment: I wondered that too. There is _no way_ the paradox monster is the same as the original Cloverfield monster.  There's a massive difference in size.

Comment: I think it will be answered in the next movie. Nevertheless, it could be the same size as the monster in the first movie. *What if it flew?*

Comment: I don't think it flew, it seemed to be stationary as it pushed its head above the clouds.

Comment: Also @Tim in the movie ground control and the husband talk about things, meaning there is more than one. Perhaps the original movie's monster is just a little one.

Comment: @Robin Director Matt Reeves: "The key to it is that the monster was a baby. The monster was suffering from separation anxiety and was absolutely disoriented and pissed, “where’s mommy?”, and terrified." 
http://www.comingsoon.net/movies/features/41100-reeves-runs-merrily-through-cloverfield

Answer (score 4):

We have two pieces of evidence to work with in determining the creature's height, the clouds and the capsule.

The cloud layer appears to be altostratus clouds, which form no lower than 2000 meters up.  We can see different types of cirrus clouds above this layer, and nothing that would indicate we were looking at a layer of lower level stratus clouds instead of altostratus.

The capsule didn't match any known reentry vehicle, though it did have the usual conical shape and rounded stony-looking heat shield.  If we assume the return vehicle had a reentry profile [like the Apollo command module](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2661/what-was-apollo-11s-reentry-speed-at-parachute-deployment) then the drogue chutes should have been deployed at around 7300 meters.  We saw no chutes as the capsule plunged into the cloud bank.

**So using this guesswork we have the creature two kilometers tall at the low end and seven or more kilometers tall at the upper end.**

Answer (score -1):

I haven’t seen *The Cloverfield Paradox*, but since I think they were landing by the Atlantic Ocean, I calculated to see his height differently. What if he were actually standing on the sea floor? So my math should yield the creature at a maximum height of over 32,000 feet.

Comment: Large sections of the Atlantic are only a few thousand feet deep. Some parts (various banks and berms) are barely submerged; http://easybusinessfinance.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Atlantic-Ocean-Water-Depths.jpg